# Datatable Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined (asp.net / js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined.
```

with data tables.

This is my HTML and JS code:

```js
function agregarFila(data) {

  let tabla = $('#tablaPedidos').DataTable();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    tabla.rows.add([
      data[i].productoID,
      data[i].producto,
      data[i].cliente,
      data[i].usuario,
      data[i].fechaCreacion,
      data[i].estado
    ]).draw();
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
        <table id="tablaPedidos" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                   <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Usuario</th>
                    <th>Fecha de creacion</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                   </tr>
                </thead>
            
            <tbody id="tablaPedidosBody">
    
            </tbody>
        </table>
    
        </div>
        
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/listaPedidos.js"></script>
```

I have no idea that may be causing this, can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html you need `tabla.row.add(...)` instead of `tabla.rows.add(...)` (notice `.row` vs `.rows`). Also, you should add `debugger;` statement before the line with add and run this code with browser dev tools open (F12 usually) - you will be able to inspect your variables and check, which methods are available.